# What is required to use TeraData with .NET?

Tags: teradata

In order to use Teradata with .NET, do I need to do a full install of the drivers on the web server or do I just need Teradata.Client.Provider.dll and the Teradata.Net.Security.Tdgss.dll?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this out by trial.  The Teradata driver does not reference any unmanaged pieces so it can be xcopy deployed to the bin directory on your web server.

I created a blog post on all of this:
http://wewillrulethegalaxytogether.blogspot.com/2013/12/how-to-use-teradata-with-net.html